# Regex pattern to match two datetime formats

Tags: python, regex

I am doing a directory listening and need to get all directory names that follow the pattern: `Feb14-2014` and `14022014-sometext`. The directory names must not contain dots, so I dont want to match `14022014-sometext.more`. Like you can see I want to match just the directories that follow the pattern `%b%d-%Y` and `%d%m%Y-textofanylengthWithoutDots`.

For the first case it should be something like `[a-zA-Z]{3}\d{2}`. I dont know how to parse the rest because my regex skills are poor, sorry. So I hope someone can tell me what the correct patterns look like. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming each directory listing is separated by a new line

```
([A-Z]\w{2}\d{1,2}\-\d{4}|\d{7,8}\-\w+)$
```

Will match both cases and will match the text only if it is uninterrupted (by dots or anything else for that matter) until it hits the end of the line.

Some notes:

- If you want to match everything except dot you may replace the final `\w+` with `[^.]+`.
- You need the multiline modifier `/m` for this to work, otherwise the `$` will match the end of the string only.
- I've not added a `^` to the start of the regex, but you may do so if each line contains a single directory
- Of course you may expand this regex to include `(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)` instead of `[A-Z]\w{2}`. I've not done this to keep it readable. I would also suggest you store this in a python array and insert it dynamically into your regex for maintainability sake.

See it in action: http://regex101.com/r/pS6iY9

Comment: thanks. One more thing: What if I would like to match `Feb14-2014_xyz` as well? So any \+w after 2014 (like for the 2nd case). How can I do that? I tried `([A-Z]\w{2}\d{1,2}\-\d{4}\w+|\d{7,8}\-\w+)$` which is not working. EDIT: I figured it out. This is working: `([A-Z]\w{2}\d{1,2}\-\d{4}\w+|[A-Z]\w{2}\d{1,2}\-\d{4}|\d{7,8}\-\w+)$`

Answer (score 0):

That's quite easy.
The best one I can make is:

```
((Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\d\d-\d\d\d\d)|(\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d-\w+)
```

The first part `((Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\d\d-\d\d\d\d)` matches the first kind of dates and the second part `(\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d-\w+)` - the second kind.